# Как создать подходящее регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть такие строки:
1. "1,2,3"
2. "1,2,3-7"
3. "1-5,8,10-12"
4. "1-4"

нужно чтобы получилось так:
1. [1,2,3]
2. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
3. [1,2,3,4,5,8,10,11,12]
4. [1,2,3,4]

Comment: А что вы попробовали сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен что можно разобрать только RegExp-ом, но если этого не требуется ...

```js
function toArray(sequence) {
  const full = (s, e) => {
    let a = []
    do {
      a.push(s)
    } while (++s <= e)
    return a
  }
  return sequence.split(/[\s,]+/)
    .map((s) => /[\s-]+/.test(s) ?
      (
        s = s.split(/[\s-]+/),
        full(+s[0], +s[1])
      ) :
      +s
    )
    .flat(Infinity)
}

console.log(toArray("1-5,8,10-12"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function uncondense(str) {
  let arr = str.split(',');
  return arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let [from, to] = item.split('-');
    if (to === undefined) {
      acc.push(+item);
    } else {
      if (+to < +from) {
        throw 'Bad input';
      }
      for (let i = +from; i <= +to; i++) {
        acc.push(i);
      }
    }
    return acc;

  }, [])
}

console.log(uncondense('1,2,3') + '');
console.log(uncondense('1,2,3-7') + '');
console.log(uncondense('1-5,8,10-12') + '');
console.log(uncondense('1-4') + '');
```